# Is there a way to know how you got your reputation points?

Tags: support, reputation

Is there a way to know the breakdown of your reputation points?

Comment: Mwahaha!  A question with a signature that Rich B won't be able to edit for at least 3 days!

Comment: @Pesto: And my rule of content vs salutations is once again proven.

Comment: Sometimes, i wish i could up-vote an edit...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You just brought a tear to my eye. <3 <3 <3

Comment: @Jon Skeet: If you had only spelled 'honor' correctly.

Comment: @Rich B: Why do the British want to waste the world's supply of the letter 'u'?  How will ftre generations live withot sch a sefl letter?

Comment: @Pesto: I cry when I think of the poor children.

Comment: http://www.angelfire.com/ok5/pearly/htmls/onion-vowels.html (theonion seems to have removed the page, unfortunately)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Click your linked username at the top of the page to open your user page. [image: username]
2. Click the Reputation tab to open the reputation graph and breakout. [image: tab]
3. Select the entire area of the graph, or enter a date range that includes your entire SO history. [image: graph]
4. Scroll through the list, noting how much each post contributed to your rep... [image: list]

Comment: Wow. Okay. You really wanted this one. All you :) +1

Comment: I love screenshots. :-)

Comment: @Shog9: And drop shadows apparently. How fancy.

Comment: I don't see where it says "Shog9" at the top of my screen.  WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?  plz help!

Comment: It doesn't show rep changes for deleted answers, at least not if you wouldn't otherwise see them.

Comment: @Brad: right. AFAIK, anything that would go away in a rep recalc isn't shown.

Answer (score 1):

[Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has a [tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can check your reputation graph on your profile page but it won't show everything (such as questions and answers which have been deleted, or bonus points achieved through things like associating accounts).

You can keep a more minute-by-minute track of your rep by looking at the reputation breakdown on your recent activity page as well. This will show you all the active posts you have made and the number of votes (up or down) and the total points gained or lost from the actions.